# Sorting a GridView

Tags: winforms

I have a question regarding GridView windows forms control. As a datasource, I am using a DataTable object. When the grid view is sorted, the DataTable's row indices are not sorted. In this way, when accessing the DataTable using indices from GridView, I get the unexpected rows. How can this situation be handled?

Comment: Is this GridView, as in .NET 1.1?  or DataGridView for >= .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Without fully knowing how you need to reference it, you can put the table's row identifier in a column and set the column's `Visible` property to **false** and have access to it that way.